# CSP blocking a JS library despite setting nonce

Tags: javascript, php, content-security-policy

I am using a certain theme for my `php` backend which uses Waves JS library. Concurrently, I am implementing `CSP` directives to protect the application from several vulnerabilities and attacks.
The drawback here is that CSP blocks some parts of [the Waves library](http://fian.my.id/Waves/) from being run, and since it's 4 years since last the developer updated the library, I couldn't get any threads in the official website to overcome this setback.Now I need to set the Waves library free from the sturdy and robust hands of CSP.

The followings are the code blocks related to the problem at hand.

**CSP header in php**:

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' $nonce; script-src 'self' $nonce");
```

**Loading Waves JS library**:

```
<script src="assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js" nonce="<?php echo $nonce; ?>"></script>
```

Even though I use a nonce for the Waves script source, as shown above (though I'm not sure whether I'm doing it correctly or not), `CSP` just blocks the Waves JS library, and throws this error:

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-048f2d51a0fd06d8e2f8b336f671201e1ecaf1f6'. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-qVj0FuZJP3W5M+MbWTwdl4yXZd2EyYdl9luuQtKVLLo='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

When I just track down the lines that are blocked by CSP, I just come to know that all the three errors belong to just one similar line of code; the following:

```
ripple.setAttribute('style', convertStyle(rippleStyle));
```

The function that it is calling is also the following:

```
function convertStyle(styleObj) {
    var style = '';

    for (var prop in styleObj) {
        if (styleObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            style += (prop + ':' + styleObj[prop] + ';');
        }
    }

    return style;
}
```

With these in mind, how can I change `ripple.setAttribute('style', convertStyle(rippleStyle))` so that the library is not blocked by CSP?
By the way, I'm not going to surrender to `unsafe-inline`, if you help me though :) .

**UPDATED**

Chrome suggests the followings as well:

```
The Content Security Policy (CSP) prevents cross-site scripting attacks by blocking inline execution of scripts and style sheets.
To solve this, move all inline scripts (e.g. onclick=[JS code]) and styles into external files.
⚠️ Allowing inline execution comes at the risk of script injection via injection of HTML script elements. If you absolutely must, you can allow inline script and styles by:
adding unsafe-inline as a source to the CSP header
adding the hash or nonce of the inline script to your CSP header.
3 directives
Directive   Element Source Location Status
style-src-attr      waves.min.js:163    blocked
style-src-attr      waves.min.js:180    blocked
style-src-attr      waves.min.js:307    blocked
Learn more: Content Security Policy - Inline Code
```

Any professional hints are much appreciated; really appreciated.

Comment: _"I just come to know that all the three errors belong to just one similar line of code"_ - is that directly from the JS resource you embedded? Or did that script perhaps in turn load other scripts dynamically, and the line is from in there? If the latter, I think you would need `strict-dynamic` - so that the trust granted to that root script, _"shall be propagated to all the scripts loaded by that root script"_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#strict-dynamic

Comment: Dear @CBroe, thanks for the comment. As mentioned in the link you offered, 'strict-dynamic' ignores any allowlist or source expressions such as 'self' or 'unsafe-inline'. Is it safe to use 'strict-dynamic' in my case? Do I risk anything if I add 'strict-dynamic' to the policy on all pages?

Comment: Dear @CBroe, I implemented 'strict-dynamic', but it threw the same error. Please see the exact error message: Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-38143f5f0d...'

Comment: I just updated the post, and added Chrome's hint on the error.

Comment: I think `ripple.setAttribute('style', ...)` counts as setting inline styles, so you would have to allow `unsafe-inline` for that to work. And I don't think you can easily replace that line with something else either - assuming that `rippleStyle` contains dynamic values determined at runtime, so you won't be able to just replace it with setting a class on the element to let your stylesheet take over the formatting based on that.

Comment: @CBroe. Once I saw a paper on CSP saying, for instance, something like $('#input').setAttribute('style', 'display'); is not accepted; however, $('#input').style.display() = 'somevalue'; was admitted by CSP. Can't that ripple line of code be changed to something like this.

Comment: If anything, it would have to be `$('#input')[0].style.display = 'somevalue'; ` - `[0]` to get the DOM element out of the jQuery object, and `display` is a property, not a method. But that should still be considered inline styling all the same.

Comment: It seems that I'm going to get rid of that Waves JS library. Words fail me to thank you dear @CBroe.